# How to access environment variables in pytest.ini addopts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have set reports location to a temp folder.
The same location I waould like to add to addopts.

Please reply if anyone knows how to do that.

in conftest.py

```
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
    reportingFolder = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'Automation_reporting')
    allureFolder = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), reportingFolder + str(now) + '\\allure-results')
    os.makedirs(allureFolder)
    print(allureFolder)
    os.environ["reporting_loc"] = reportingFolder
    os.environ["allure_loc"] = allureFolder
    parser.addini('reporting_loc', paths = reportingFolder)
    parser.addini('allure_loc', paths = reportingFolder)
```

in pytest.ini

```
addopts = --md-report -v --alluredir="./reports/allure/allure-results"  --verbose --html=reporting_loc/output.html
```

In pytest.ini
I want to replace "allure_loc" everytime when I run the test suite.

Comment: Why do you want to change it in pytest.ini `addopts`? AFAIK pytest config file is read once, before any conftest.py code execution. Is your goal just to use different `--alluredir` and `--html` each execution of the `pytest` command?

Comment: I want to store all reports(allure, html reports) in temp folder. (If I am running it in local, i would like to store them in windows temp folder and while running it in aws cloud, I would like to store them in linux temp folder. Is there a way to do this? 
Either via scrip in conftest.py or setting a path in pytest.ini ?

Comment: I tried to do this using addoption (like mentioned below)
```
parser.addoption("--alluredir", action="store", default=allureFolder) #allureFolder = this variable has the temp location(from the lines I mentioned in my query)
```

But this is giving me conflict error.

argparse.ArgumentError: argument --alluredir: conflicting option string: --alluredir site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I have posted one of possible solutions, please, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some implementation. It replaces your passed parameters with `tempfile` files and folders.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory, TemporaryFile

import pytest
from _pytest.stash import StashKey

temp_resources = StashKey()


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.stash[temp_resources] = []
    alluredir = getattr(config.option, "allure_report_dir", None)
    html = getattr(config.option, "htmlpath", None)
    if alluredir:
        temp_dir = TemporaryDirectory(
            prefix="allure_report_dir_",
            suffix=alluredir
        )
        # temp_dir._finalizer.detach()  # Do not remove directory
        config.stash[temp_resources].append(temp_dir)
        config.option.allure_report_dir = temp_dir.name
    if html:
        temp_file = TemporaryFile(
            prefix="htmlpath_",
            suffix=html,
            # delete=False  # Do not remove file
        )
        config.stash[temp_resources].append(temp_file)
        config.option.htmlpath = temp_file.name


@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    for temp_resource in session.config.stash[temp_resources]:
        if isinstance(temp_resource, TemporaryDirectory):
            temp_resource.cleanup()
        else:
            temp_resource.close()
```

I am not sure when you want to perform actions with reports so I don't know when to cleanup these resources. I have commented out lines that keep resources, so now they will be deleted in the end of `pytest` session.

`pytest_configure` hook uses passed `--html` and `--alluredir` parameters as temp file/dir suffixes. Also it stores these resources in `stash` under some key.

`pytest_sessionfinish` hook cleans up all temp resources from `stash`.

You can comment out `pytest_sessionfinish` and uncomment all lines from `pytest_configure` to keep all created files even after pytest execution finish.

Please note that now `--html` and `--alluredir` must be just suffixes, not paths. Example: `--alluredir=some_path --html output.html` will create following resources:

`%temp dir of OS%/allure_report_dir_%random_hash%_some_path`

`%temp dir of OS%/htmlpath_%random_hash%_output.html`

Implementation really depends on your scenario. Anyway, I hope you will get my idea and will be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you!. "config.option.allure_report_dir = temp_dir.name". This helped me to set temp dir as alluredir.

But where can we find these "config.option.allure_report_dir" options list.
How do you know its "allure_report_dir" as an option. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: List of options is stored in `config.option` variable. `allure_report_dir` is specified as destination to save cmdline arg value in source code of `allure-pytest` plugin. https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/master/allure-pytest/src/plugin.py#L22